# Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, oracle

this is my code and i am using in edit.php for editing my database but when i open this page directly in browser i am getting error `Notice: Undefined index: OPRID`

but now i have open page this path

```
Optr_Edit.php?OPRID=<?=$objResult["OPRID"];?>
```

its right yaa wrong... tell mee

```
<?
include ('connection.php');
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM OPERATOR WHERE OPRID =  '".$_GET["OPRID"]."' ";
$objParse = oci_parse ($ora_conn, $strSQL);
oci_execute ($objParse,OCI_DEFAULT);
$objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse);

if(!$objResult)
{  
    echo "Not found OPRID=".$_GET["OPRID"];
} else {  
....
?>
```

Comment: Does your url have a field named OPRID in it?

Comment: As the error show there is no value comming like `$_GET["OPRID"]` to try isset checking

Comment: pass `OPRID` as get parameter in the url when directly loading the script.

Comment: Most probably `$_GET["OPRID"]` is not set..

Comment: plz explain your ans .....

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/path/edit.php?OPRID=hello
```

Using this URL, `$_GET["OPRID"]` would contain "hello". If you don't pass anything in via the URL like that i.e. `http://www.yourdomain.com/path/edit.php` then `$_GET["OPRID"]` will not be set.

Comment: now see my edit cade.....

Comment: You're mixing up which page is which by the looks of things. Assuming the code you posted is for `edit.php` when accessing that page you should have `edit.php?OPRID=value`. Is this what you're doing?

Comment: so what i am doing here...

Answer (score 0):

$GET contains the CGI parameters when the php module is called from another html form. If you just open the php file directly, there won't be any parameters unless you supply them by using mypage.php?OPRID=XX

Answer (score 0):

`GET` parameters are parameters from the URL.

For example:

> http://www.example.com?**OPRID=test**

You can now get the value "test" via the `$_GET` dictionary:

```
print $_GET["OPRID"];
```

The output will be

> test

Comment: hello.......see my code now..

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it like:

```
edit.php?OPRID=<your value here>
```

then the $_GET array looks like:

```
array('OPRID',<your value here>);
```

You can check if an index exists with

```
if(isset($_GET['OPRID']))
{
     //DO STUFF
}
else
{
     //ECHO: NO OPRID FOUND
}
```

Please make sure you escape the values from $_GET, because you an attacker could easily type in:

```
edit.php?OPRID=1"or"1"="1
```

or worse. Read more about that: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

You can access your GET, POST, COOKIE SERVER and ENV arrays by utilising build in function `filter_input()`

[php.net Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Using this function you will not get an errors or notices logged and your variables will always have a value and be sanitized.

EDIT:

Instead of using

`$_GET["OPRID"]`

several times you can use

`$oprid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'OPRID');`

once in your script. After this line you have a variable `$oprid` with a defined value which will be `null` if the index `OPRID` in `$_GET` was empty not set.

*Excerpt from php.net:*

**Return Values:**

Value of the requested variable on success, FALSE if the filter fails, or NULL if the variable_name variable is not set. If the flag FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is used, it returns FALSE if the variable is not set and NULL if the filter fails.

Comment: how to use function in here tell me..